# What Excel function and process would I use to calculate time between one column and another (6:55AM/3:00PM)?

Tags: excel, function, time

I need to determine the best way, in Excel, to use the start time in two columns (6:55/AM) and the end time in two columns (1:00/PM) to make 'if'statements such as: If >= 3:00 before 10:00AM, then 'yes'. Can anyone tell me if this is even possible? And what would be the best way for me to start?

I have pulled the 4 columns (6:55/AM/1:00/PM) into two different columns (6:55AM/1:00PM) and then tried using this formula: `=text(x16-y16,"hh:mm")` but I cannot get it to do anything further. I have searched throughout Stack Overflow and don't see anything that resembles this specific situation.

I need to be able to create if statements such as If >= 3:00 before 10:00AM, then 'yes'. So in the above example, yes would be the response, but if my first columns were to be (7:00/AM) then the response will return no.

Comment: _"I have pulled the 4 columns (6:55/AM/1:00/PM) into two different columns (6:55AM/1:00PM)..."_. Can you show us the method you used to do this? Because you would be better off ensuring that you are using an actual time format instead of a textual representation of your time.

Comment: Of course!  This is what I have done:  =C16&""&D16.  This simply makes the 6:55 in one column and AM in the next column be combined...  I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this or not.  I wonder if there is a way to do this and then turn it into military time where 3:00 would be 15:00?

Comment: Now, what if you did something like `=TIMEVALUE(C16 & " " & D16)` instead, and format the column as a time format? I assume that the `6:55` is formatted as text since you are having to combine it with the `AM`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your time values are text (else you would get something very different if you concatenated as you show, I suggest, to convert them to "real" times: *(and This will work if the value in `C1` is a date/real time or text.)*

```
=C1+IF(D1="AM",0,0.5)
```

This formula will, in effect, turn the value in `C1` into a real time, and add 12 hours to it (1/2 of a day) if the value in `D1` is not `AM`.

**NOTE:** *(provoked by a comment of @K.Dᴀᴠɪs)* This formula does no error checking at all, assuming all of your data is how you show in your examples..  If that is necessary, you will need to modify the formula.

**Edit** To check that something has been entered in `C1`, as requested in a comment, just do that.  eg:

```
=IF(C1="","",C1+IF(AND(LEN(C1)>0,D1="AM"),0,0.5))
```

Comment: That's a good way to do it. I would personally add a check just to make sure that you are not accidentally adding half a day if `D1` is blank or there's a typo. `=C1+IF(D1="AM",0,IF(D1="PM",0.5,NA()))` for example

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Point taken.  And there are other data input error checks that might be useful.

Comment: I'm sure there is, for example checking that the time is actually a time (otherwise it could be treated as `0` a/k/a 12:00 AM), but my major concern is something like `A.M.` or `A M` being treated as `False`. Obviously there's not a simple method to ensure that the input data is actually correct. Mainly a check on consistency was where I was going.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Not only that -- If data input validation is a problem, I would be inclined to apply that at the point of data entry. In other words, much earlier in the process than what we are being presented. And the method would depend on how the data is actually being entered -- and that information is not currently available.

Comment: That's fair enough

Comment: Actually, this (=C1+IF(D1="AM",0,0.5)) did the trick...  :)  However, if there is nothing in field C1, I would like this to not populate anything.  What more do I need to add to this to make it happen?   @RRosenfeld, to your questions/comments.  Those fields are forced to be entered in the format of hh:mm.  Whatever is added will go to that format and the user is required to verify that the time is correct.  :)  That should solve the issue you were asking about, correct?

Comment: @KristenBecker Just check that there's something in `C1` before doing that.  See my Edit to my answer.

Comment: @KristenBecker Why not just force the user to enter in the format of `hh:mm a` or `hh:mm p`? Then you don't have to do any conversions after the fact.  And your requirement of `hh:mm` would not prevent someone from entering data in a military 24 hr format.  So you might want to change the formula to check for `PM` rather than `AM` if your not going to make any other changes.  Or you could just use a user form with dropdowns for  the hour, minute, and AM/PM.  Then convert it when you write from the user form to the worksheet. The user form would give you maximum control over the input.

Comment: I didn't even think of a user form!!  I will try that.  Thank you, Ron!

Comment: @KristenBecker Microsoft's datetimepicker control is not installed by default in modern versions.  It can be installed (involves downloading a dll file and registering it on each computer where this will be used) and that is a viable solution if you have control over the computers on which it will be used.  If you don't have that control, you may need to develop (or find one that you can download) your own version that is distributable.

Comment: I have been playing with the UserForm option all afternoon.  I think it might work but I have a bit more to think on. :)  Thank you for the suggestion!  Yes, I did find the 'datetimepicker' on my computer so I think I'm okay.  I will be sure to have others in my agency test to be sure there won't be any 'errors' using my document.

Comment: @KristenBecker There are a number of articles, both on SO and elsewhere, about how to add that control if it is missing from some of them.